# PFQuery caching using fromLocalDataStore() with saveEventually()

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I am querying Parse to return a list of all Tournament objects that the user created. However, `saveEventually()` unpins the objects from the LDS and so if they have network connection, the query returns empty.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var query = PFQuery(className:"Tournament")
    query.orderByAscending("createdAt")
    query.whereKey("createdBy", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser())
    query.fromLocalDatastore()
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if (error == nil) {
            self.tournaments = objects;
            self.tableView.reloadData()
            PFObject.pinAllInBackground(objects)
        } else {
            NSLog("Error: %@ %@", error, error.userInfo!)
        }
    }
}
```

I'd like to keep all objects ever created cached locally so that they can be accessed offline. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You could just use `saveInBackgroundWithBlock` in conjunction with a pining the data (saving it to the local datastore). That will both sync it to the LDS and your Parse server, without removing anything from the LDS when the network save operation is completed.

Even better, you could create a category for PFQuery that defines a new method called `saveToCacheAndNetworkInBackgroundWithBlock:` (or something less verbose) that does those two actions without using `saveEventually`.

Comment: What will happen if we call `saveInBackgroundWithBlock` when the app is offline? Will it save it eventually once a network connection is restored like [saveEventually](https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#objects-offline/iOS) does? It's important all data is synced to Parse.

Comment: If you call `saveInBackgroundWithBlock:` when the user is offline, the request will fail and return an error and parse will make no retry attempt.